# Приведение библиотеки логов под фасад slf4j

Tags: java, логирование, opensource, log4j, slf4j

У меня есть свой небольшой проект (модуль), который я хочу вылить в open source, но он зависит от моего кастомного логгера (SLogger'a). SLogger является надстройкой над log4j2. Я хочу разорвать зависимость моего модуля с SLogger'ом чтобы люди могли сами выбирать библиотеку для логгирования. Как мне подвести мой SLogger под фасад slf4j?

Comment: Насколько понимаю, достаточно будет использовать Logger из нужного пакета.

Comment: А что мешает напрямую использовать slf4j? В зависимости от того какая реализация присутствует для него, тот логгер и будет использоваться.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov потому что мой проект состоит из кучи модулей, и он действительно очень большой. (около 1 млн строк кода) Переписывать везде логгирование на slf4j работа очень большая. Вопрос даже можно переформулировать. Как написать свою реализацию slf4j? На самом деле реализация уже написана и её надо подогнать под фасад slf4j.

Comment: @Etki дело в том, что я использую во всём проекте (он состоит из 25-ти различных модулей) свой кастомный SLogger, который надстройка на log4j. Но теперь некоторый модули я хочу вывести в open-source, но без зависимости на мой SLogger (не все же хотят юзать мою библу для логгирования). Так вот как бы нужно подводить мой логгер под фасад slf4j?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov а нельзя дергать в классе обертке SLogger методы не log4j а slf4j? или я чего то не понимаю.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov вопорос не в том как изменить SLogger, а как его сделать имплементацией slf4j api?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov конечно SLogger всё равно придётся менять чтобы подогнать под интерфейсы. Но что именно надо реализовывать и как потом настраивать slf4j для работы с кастомной библиотекой и использовать эту кастомную библиотеку (SLogger), как реализацию slf4j?

Comment: Смотрите, в чем профит делать его реализацией  slf4j api? Это будет удобно только в случае если у вас в проекте дергается api slf4j. Но как я понял  из коментария выше, в проекте напрямую вызываются методы SLogger. Т.е. это не изменит ситуацию. Я вижу тут два варианта: переписать SLogger c использованием slf4j или же убрать из проекта прямые вызыва SLogger на slf4j  и переписывать SLogger как одну из реализаций  slf4j

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov "убрать из проекта прямые вызыва SLogger на slf4j и переписывать SLogger как одну из реализаций slf4j" именно это я и собираюсь сделать :) отлично, что вы меня поняли! Вот вопрос в том, как переписать SLogger так чтобы он был реализацией slf4j?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov и как потом эту реализацию подключить?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov сделать реализацию slf4j api которая в свою очередь будет дергать log4j это очень замечательно (=

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а почему вам кажется это плохой идей? Ведь slf4j api это просто интерфейс? (Фишка в том, что SLogger это моя реализация) другию люди смогу подключать свою через slf4j api, только мне непонятно куда двигаться, чтобы сделать свою имплементацию slf4j и главное как её потом подключить если её не будет в maven rep, просто jar-ником?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov сначало показалась плохой идеей, потом подумав пришел к мысли, что не нет, если у вас там не тупо делегирование вызовов метода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Четкой инструкции не дам. Но могу посоветовать куда копать. У slf4j есть несколько [реализаций](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html). Среди которых slf4j-simple, которая перенаправляет весь выход в System.err. Можно покопаться в ее исходниках (там всего 5 классов) и переписать под свои нужды. Касаемо зависимости, можно распространять jar архивом или же опубликовать в [maven central](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662546/how-to-deploy-my-open-source-projects-using-mavens-central-repository).

UDP 
шаблон для собственной реализации slf4j api

```
package org.slf4j.impl;

import org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder;
```

public class StaticLoggerBinder implements LoggerFactoryBinder {

```
private final static StaticLoggerBinder SINGLETON = new StaticLoggerBinder();
private final ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;

private StaticLoggerBinder() {
    loggerFactory = new CustomLoggerFactoryImp();
}

@Override
public ILoggerFactory getLoggerFactory() {
    return loggerFactory;
}

@Override
public String getLoggerFactoryClassStr() {
    return "CustomLoggerFactory";
}

public static StaticLoggerBinder getSingleton() {
    return SINGLETON;
}

private static class CustomLoggerFactoryImp implements ILoggerFactory {

    @Override
    public Logger getLogger(String name) {
        return /*"реализация org.slf4j.Logger"*/ null;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Да, уже скачал и simple и NOP. Буду копать в ту сторону :) И нет, не просто делегирование методов :) Спасибо.

Comment: думаю, когда закончу оформлю как ответ, твой ответ лайкнул)

Comment: было бы любопытно вглянуть. от души)

Comment: Тут сложная задачка :) У меня есть методы, которые не предусмотрены фасадом slf4j, получается их подогнать никак не получится? Люди ведь всё равно смогут юзать только то, что если в slf4j или есть какой-то обходной путь? :)

Comment: На то оно и общее апи, естественно в нем не будет специфичных фич библиотек логирования

Comment: Фууф, посоветовался с коллегой и появился новый вопрос. Предположим у нас есть уже готовая реализация log4j api (она extend log4j core). Её реально как-то подогнать под slf4j api?

Comment: а насчёт адаптации log4j реализации к slf4j не подскажите?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov я не знаю, что из себя представляет ваша реализация, но, мне кажется, что если в методе `getLogger` возвращать вами переделанный log4j то должно заработать

Comment: Спасибо) Попробую :D

Comment: К сожалению, задача немного изменилась и буду подводить под фасад log4j. Ваш ответ пометил как верный, спасибо.